ag grid agSelectCellEditor (dropdown) style broken after upgrade
I've updated ag-grid from 22.1.1 to 28.2.1, everything seems to be fine, except the dropdowns. The look and feel of the dropdowns is completely messed up now.
before:

after:

I have the imports in the scss file:
@import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";

For what it's worth here's a stackblitz where it's working on v19, I'm just looking to migrate to +V23 and have the dropdown working
before (ag grid V19 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-button-renderer-dropdown-zbbyan?file=package.json)
and here's a stackblitz with v28, where the data in the cell is not displayed in it's entirety but it's wrapped instead like an excel cell, and also it needs to be clicked twice for the content to be displayed.
after (ag grid V28 https://stackblitz.com/edit/finitelooper-ng16-dmbxnj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

links are not working

@ I've updated the links, feel free to have another look
